# DAX Rule with 2 IFs

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

How would you write the following conditions in DAX (for Power BI) for a measure named RULE:

• If Monthly Net Order Quantity >4 or Monthly Average Final Run Time > 28, returns 1

• If Monthly Average Final Run Time is blank, return blank

• Otherwise return 0

I don't have any DAX knowledge so anyone out there please help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lots of conditions, sometimes it's easier to write a `SWITCH`:

```
RULE =
SWITCH( TRUE(),
    ISBLANK ( [Monthly Average Final Run Time] ),
    BLANK(),
    [Monthly Net Order Quantity] > 4 || [Monthly Average Final Run Time] > 28,
    1,
    0
)
```

[This article](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/) explains the `SWITCH( TRUE(), ... )` construction nicely.

Comment: Thank you so much (for the link and the expression) ! It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Monthly Net Order Quantity` and `Monthly Average Final Run Time` are existing measures, then:

```
RULE =
IF (
    [Monthly Net Order Quantity] > 4
        || [Monthly Average Final Run Time] > 28,
    1,
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( [Monthly Average Final Run Time] ),
        BLANK (),
        0
    )
)
```